# QGIS - always disable the "add saved file to map" checkbox in dialog

Tags: checkbox, dialog, qgis

I often use the "Save as.." dialog and just want the exported file there. But he always enables the checkbox "add saved file to map". I really dislike it that way and does not make any sense to perma-enable it.

Is there a way to permanently disable it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far this is a **known issue** and has now been **added** **to** the **feature list** as discussed in https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131947/how-to-always-disable-the-add-saved-file-to-map-checkbox-in-save-as